# Load object only when necessary

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a mapping for the Slab object that has the mapping references to objects and SlabPDO SlabInstructions. I would like to do selects, always carry the object SlabPDO and load SlabInstructions only when necessary. Is there any way to do this? Below an example of mapping:

```
<id name="Id" column="Id_Slab" type="Int64">
  <generator class="Geraes.GLib.GDomainBasis.CustomTableHiLoGenerator, GLib.GDomainBasis" />
</id>

<property name="Mill" column="Mill" type="String" length="2" not-null="true" />

<property name="SlabId" column="Slab_Id" type="String" length="20" not-null="true" />

<property name="PieceId" column="Piece_Id" type="String" length="20" not-null="true" />

<one-to-one name="SlabPDO" class="SlabPDO" cascade="all" fetch="join"/>

<set name="SlabInstructions" generic="true" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="all" fetch="join">
  <key column="Id_Slab" />
  <one-to-many class="SlabInstruction"/>
</set>
```

Best Regards!

Comment: Can you translate your title into English please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding these two mapping property `lazy="true"` `fetch="select"` consult the docs http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching

here's your solution

```
<set name="SlabInstructions" generic="true" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all"
  fetch="select">
  <key column="Id_Slab" />
  <one-to-many class="SlabInstruction"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

The problem is that in 90% of cases, will need the child objects. In other cases, is that I will need to discard the loading of child objects. What would be the best approach?

Comment: When you write a query, you can specify to load child objects (`left join fetch`). So the mapping can be lazy, to save the unnecessary loading of child objects in 10% of cases.